# Software Center keeps asking for a CD/DVD when installing applications

Tags: software-center, software-sources

I just got Linux Ubuntu, but I have a problem. I am trying to download Wine and Flash but I keep on getting this:

CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 11.10 *Oneiric Ocelot* - Release amd64 (20111012)' is required

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Software Center menu, click Edit->Software Sources.

In the Software Sources, uncheck the Cdrom box, then try installing something.

Comment: Cool. Hope you'll like it.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. I run Lubuntu 11.10 and I kept getting same error message whenever I wanted to update via update manager. Also when I wanted to install Adobe acroread.

This is how I solved it: In Update manager, go to setup in the bottom left corner(I am danish, so I hope that was correct translated). There I went to to Sources and look if you have checked anything with CD. It was OK. Then I looked in "other software", and hello, there was something interesting. Why was several lines of CD:  "Lubuntu 11.10 *Oneiric Ocelot* - Release amd64 (20111012) checked? I uncheced, had to put in password. Closed, and went to update. Voalá! It worked. And I also was able to install my Adobe Acroread!